# Dialog box closes slowly after clicking send button

Tags: database, web-applications

In my webapp, I have a send dialogue box which sends the data to a selected email address. The  issue is that the dialog box disappears after few seconds of clicking send button which makes the user click send button multiple times as a result of which same mail is sent multiple times. 
What I think is that this can be a function of the speed of the DB (and probably the size of the data).

Comment: It got resolved by using the javscript blockUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it takes several second to receive confirmation then you must reflect that in the UI, by putting up a "wait" cursor, disabling the "Send" button, possibly dimming the dialog box etc. There's nothing wrong with taking a few seconds as long as you make sure the user is aware and cannot click Send a second time

Even if you expect the operation to be nearly instantaneous in most cases, you STILL must reflect the possibility of a delay in the UI.  That's just a fundamental UI design principle.